# Fastest way to find whether two sets are different?

Tags: c++, c++11, set

What is the fastest way to find out whether two sets are different?
Using `std::set_difference` gets me all the differences, but I only need to know about the first diff.

Currently, I am doing the following:

```
bool areSetsDifferent(const std::set<MyClass> &myClassSet1, const std::set<MyClass> &myClassSet2) {
    if (myClassSet1.size() != myClassSet2.size()) {
        return true;
    }
    std::vector<MyClass> diffs(myClassSet1.size());
    auto iter = std::set_difference(myClassSet1.begin(), myClassSet1.end(), myClassSet2.begin(), myClassSet2.end(),
            diffs.begin());
    return iter != diffs.begin();
}
```

Comment: *"I only need to know about the first diff"*  **What** do you need to know about it?

Comment: @DrewDormann, I meant that once I know that one diff exists, I can exit my method.

Comment: Then Alex has an *excellent* answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`std::set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) has an [`operator!=`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/operator_cmp).

```
bool areSetsDifferent(const std::set<MyClass> &myClassSet1, const std::set<MyClass> &myClassSet2) {
    return myClassSet1 != myClassSet2;
}
```